# Missing records if add "NOT IN"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of doctor names and states.

```
f_name  | l_name | state
MICHAEL | CRANE  | 
HAL     | CRANE  | MD
THOMAS  | ROMINA | DE
```

And so on.

What I want is to get all doctors that are NOT in MD. However, if I write this expression I'm missing those with NULL values for state.

```
SELECT *
FROM doctors
WHERE state NOT IN ('MD')
```

I don't understand the issue. I was able to fix it by adding

```
OR state IS NULL
```

Obviously it has something to due with NOT IN (or IN) not handling NULL. Can anyone explain this for me? Is there an alternative for what I was trying to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative - you would use the `NVL()` function (or `COALESCE()` if you want to stick to the ANSI standard):

```
SELECT * FROM doctors
 WHERE NVL(state, '@@') NOT IN ('MD')
```

However you don't really need to use `NOT IN` here - it's only necessary when you have multiple values, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM doctors
 WHERE NVL(state, '@@') NOT IN ('MD','PA')
```

With one value you can just use `=` (or in this case, `!=` or `<>`):

```
SELECT * FROM doctors
 WHERE NVL(state, '@@') != 'MD'
```

In Oracle SQL, `NULL` can't be compared to other values (not even other `NULL`s). So `WHERE NULL = NULL`, for example, will return zero rows. You do `NULL` comparisons with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: "In Oracle SQL, NULL can't be compared to other values (not even other NULLs)" Which makes sense if you think about it.  How do you compare an unknown to a known?  Or an unknown to another unknown?

Comment: Or rather, NULL can be compared to other values, but the result is always "unknown".

Comment: It does make sense and that is the way it works in the ANSI standard as well. In SQL Server one can turn off `ANSI NULLs` and then `NULL = NULL` will be true.

Comment: @DavidFaber It wouldn't have helped here. Even if that setting is toggled, it only applies to literal `NULL`s, it doesn't change anything that comes from a column or a variable.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but it might be worth stating that you have to be careful picking your fixed values so you can be sure it can never appear in real data, even in the future - probably safe with `@@` for state code, but something to bear in mind in the general case. I tend to prefer the more explicit `or is null` anyway as it's clearer what you're doing, but personal opinion. And that applying a function to a column can stop any index being used, but again if you're looking for nulls anyway that's rather moot...

Comment: Agreed that `OR IS NULL` is better in the vast majority of cases, including this one, but the OP asked for an alternative. And yes, if one is going to use a function like this then it might be best to add a function-based index.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I wasn't sure if the approach I was taking made the most sense, but it sounds like OR IS NULL is completely acceptable to use.

Comment: Yes, `OR IS NULL` is completely acceptable. `NVL()` or `COALESCE()` may be helpful in some circumstances where you want a function-based index, which would be more likely if using `IN` or `=` than `NOT IN` or `!=`.

Comment: I still think Oracle is wrong, and that the result of `state not in ('MD')` should include all NULL values. In my opinion, a NULL value is not necessarily unknown. It can be an un-entered but known value. Why isn't it entered ? Because you can. Because the column was not protected (NOT NULL). Maybe it is unknown, maybe it isn't. Fact it, it wasn't filled in. Stating it is unknown, is an assumption.

Comment: @tvCa, you misunderstand. `NULL` means that the value is undefined or unknown. If you know the value then don't use `NULL`. Strictly speaking `NULL` isn't a value at all. One can't compare something that isn't a value to something that is a value.

Comment: I'm not saying you should leave columns empty on purpose. You didn't understand what I'm saying. We're passed what humans (or other code) has put into the database. We're retrieving data here. I'm saying : a NULL value may indicate a lot. You say : undefined or unknown. Yes. And also : irrelevant. Maybe some other things. But it CAN include the fact a user SHOULD enter a value, but hasn't. I'm not saying that is good, I wouldn't do that, I'm just stating a fact.

Comment: @David Faber: " One can't compare something that isn't a value to something that is a value". SQL> select 'oh oh' from dual where NULL = 'something'; no rows selected SQL> - Oops, I just compared NULL to something that is a value, and the result was correct (false boolean). No error thrown whatsoever.

Comment: "a NULL value may indicate a lot" - then the user is using it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As noted already, you don't know that Michael Crane's state isn't Maryland. It's NULL, which can be read as representing "don't know". It might be Maryland, or it might not be. `NOT IN ('MD')` only finds those values *known* not to be `'MD'`.

If you have a filter `WHERE x`, you can use `MINUS` to find exactly those records where `x` is not true (where `x` is either false or unknown).

```
select *
from doctors
minus
select *
from doctors
where state in ('MD');
```

This has one big advantage over anything involving `IS NULL` or `NVL`: it's immediately obvious exactly which records you *don't* want to see. You don't have to worry about accidentally missing one case where `NULL` isn't covered in your condition, and you don't have to worry about records that happen to match whatever dummy value you use with `NVL`.

It's generally not good for performance on Oracle, accessing the table twice, but for one-off queries, depending on the table size, the time saved writing the query can be more than the added execution time.

Comment: What does Oracle's optimizer make of the above statement? I just tried it on a relatively big table in my own DB and got a not very nice plan -- in fact, even worse than using `NVL(state, '@@')` even though both wound up with full table access.

Comment: @DavidFaber Yeah, the optimizer doesn't do a good job here. It accesses the table twice.

Comment: I also tried this using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and that fell in between the `NVL()` method and the `MINUS` method. Of course which works best would depend on a number of factors.

Comment: @DavidFaber It's probably worth adding a note about it, and I've now done so. I'm not sure which `WHERE NOT EXISTS` approach you're thinking of: I was thinking of `select * from doctors where not exists(select 1 from dual where doctors.state in ('MD'));`. Is that what you had in mind too?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM doctors d1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM doctors d2 WHERE d2.id = d1.id AND d2.state IN ('MD'));`

Comment: @DavidFaber Ah, okay, I wouldn't expect the optimizer to avoid reading the table twice in that case. It might be able to do so with the version in my comment, but it becomes harder to read than your answer.

Comment: I really liked your explanation at to WHY IS NOT doesn't cover the NULL, it make a lot of sense once I read that. So big thanks! Although I think David has a better alternative. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside database, null are not physical string values("null"), it simply says no value. So, if you compare NULLs to anything, it will not be equal or not equal. Even, two NULL's are not equal. You can only check whetherr a value is NULL or not but you can't compare it to other values.